# Font shows up as Arial instead of Times

Tags: posts, css

I am the webmaster of Palo Alto High School's online publication, The Paly Voice. We're using Wordpress, and for some reason occasionally chunks of stories change fonts. [Here](http://palyvoice.com/2012/09/02/students-give-back-through-amigos-program/) is an example.

I inspected it, and there's no surrounding element - just text. But why? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paragraphs that show up differently are not inside `<p>` tags. Therefore the font rule in your `story.css` file (line 111) does not apply to them. To fix this you can do one of two things:

1. Put the paragraphs that are showing up with the wrong font inside
   `<p>` tags.
2. Add a new rule in story.css for the entire section that sets the font. The rule would be something like this:

   ```
   .story-content {
       font-family: Georgia;
       font-family: Georgia, serif;
       font-size: 14px;
       line-height: 1.7;
       margin: 20px 0;
   }
   ```